# Troubling defining a 'bean' , "Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Tried running my spring boot app and my compiler says;
" Field repo in com.example.hello_world.UserService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)"

New to spring boot so I'm not exactly sure why my project isn't running. Tried messing around with different annotations, even using "basePackages={"com.example.hello_world"} " and adding different dependencies to my xml file but nothing seems to work. Not exactly sure which file would be my configuration file. 
M
My compiler

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-08 13:30:58.527  INFO 904 --- [           main] c.e.hello_world.HelloWorld1Application   : Starting HelloWorld1Application on LAPTOP-QBE4L7C0 with PID 904 (C:\Users\Tristan\eclipse-workspace\hello_world-1\target\classes started by Tristan in C:\Users\Tristan\eclipse-workspace\hello_world-1)
2020-02-08 13:30:58.530  INFO 904 --- [           main] c.e.hello_world.HelloWorld1Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-08 13:30:58.914  INFO 904 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-02-08 13:30:58.962  INFO 904 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 39ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-02-08 13:30:59.390  INFO 904 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-08 13:30:59.397  INFO 904 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-08 13:30:59.397  INFO 904 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-02-08 13:30:59.519  INFO 904 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-08 13:30:59.519  INFO 904 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 949 ms
2020-02-08 13:30:59.582  WARN 904 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#420745d7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#420745d7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2020-02-08 13:30:59.584  INFO 904 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-02-08 13:30:59.657  INFO 904 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-08 13:30:59.728 ERROR 904 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repo in com.example.hello_world.UserService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

My xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello_world-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello_world-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

First File of my project,

```
    package com.example.hello_world;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories

public class HelloWorld1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Service File
UserService.Java

```
    package com.example.hello_world;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service

@EntityScan("com.example.hello_world")
@ComponentScan("com.example.hello_world")
public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repo;

        public List<UserInfo> listAll()
        {
            return repo.findAll();
        }


        public void save(UserInfo User)
        {
            repo.save(User);
        }


        public UserInfo get(Long id)
        {
            return repo.findById(id).get();
        }

        public void delete(Long id)
        {
            repo.deleteById(id);
        }
}
```

My Respository File
UserRepository.jav

```
    package com.example.hello_world;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



@Service

@EntityScan("com.example.hello_world")
@ComponentScan("com.example.hello_world")
public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repo;

        public List<UserInfo> listAll()
        {
            return repo.findAll();
        }


        public void save(UserInfo User)
        {
            repo.save(User);
        }


        public UserInfo get(Long id)
        {
            return repo.findById(id).get();
        }

        public void delete(Long id)
        {
            repo.deleteById(id);
        }
}
```

My Controller File
App Controller.java

```
    package com.example.hello_world;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.ui.*;

@Controller
public class AppController
{

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String ViewHomePage(Model model)
    {
        List<UserInfo> listUserInfo = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listUserInfo", listUserInfo);

        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: You pasted two times your `UserService` class instead of the `UserRepository`.

Comment: you can also remove the entityscan and component scan, the @SpringBootApplication will scan for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing things in the good way I'm afraid.

You want to have a Spring Boot application, with Controller and Repository. For the controller, your configuration seems okay, but for the Repository, it is not.

1. Make up your mind between Hibernate and EclipseLink. Your are importing both in your project. If you do not have any intention of using EclipseLink, then trust me, remove it and use Hibernate.
2. You are not importing the good dependencies in your POM. When doing a Spring Boot project that needs a JPA configuration, you have to use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you don't, then you will end up missing certains mandatory beans, like `entityManagerFactoryBean`. Indeed, the starter dependencies are made to load a bunch of AutoConfiguration classes, and one if for configuring the `entityManagerFactoryBean`.

Here is the POM I'd recommend for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello_world-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello_world-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Give it a go, and let me know the result.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seemed to have solved that particular error. Only other error I'm getting now is " Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class " But I know that's as simple as adding a driver to my classpath.

Comment: This is what was in my Repository file btw,                                                     
package com.example.hello_world;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.hello_world", entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository <UserInfo , Long>  {
 
 

}

Comment: If it worked for you, don’t hesitate to mark the answer. It might help others

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. My problem was that I forgot to `unexclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in my `application-dev.properties:`

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```